# Reversing a CSS animation from current postion to a new one after leaving hover

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I want to have a sidebar that changes color when hovering over it by changing the background position of the gradient but I also want to reverse the animation after the mouse leaves hover. But the problem with my current code is that when I remove the hover, it does the animation from the end to the start and not from where it is at the current position to where I want it to go. Here is the code snippet for the animation:

```css
.side-nav{

    background: linear-gradient(#00bcd4, #e91e63, #3f51b5, #00bcd4);
    background-size: 100% 500%;
    background-position: 0 40%;
    animation: out 2s linear reverse;
}
@keyframes out {
    from{background-position: 0 400%;}
    to{background-position: 0 40%;}
}
.side-nav:hover{
    animation: backcolor 20s linear infinite reverse;
}
@keyframes backcolor {
    from{background-position: 0 40%;}
    to{background-position: 0 400%;}
}
```

For example, if I hover over the side menu with the mouse and the animation starts, but I remove the mouse before the animation is completely done, I want the animation to reverse starting from where it reached.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not solvable with just CSS since CSS doesn't track the animation progress. You have to explore some animation libraries to do that. I'll be interested to see if anyone has a pure CSS solution for this.

Comment: @Prajwal Oh thanks, but do you know any specific library to use

Comment: I'm not sure if you need animation here at all. Looks like transitions are enough. At least if you don't need your sidebar bg beeing animated all the time.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect, you need to use the animation-play-state property. When the mouse leaves the hover, you should pause the current animation and start a new one that plays in reverse, starting from the current position. Here's an updated code snippet that should work:

```
.side-nav{
    background: linear-gradient(#00bcd4, #e91e63, #3f51b5, #00bcd4);
    background-size: 100% 500%;
    background-position: 0 40%;
    animation: out 2s linear reverse;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* stay at the final position of the animation */
    animation-play-state: paused; /* pause the animation */
}
@keyframes out {
    from {background-position: 0 400%;}
    to {background-position: 0 40%;}
}
.side-nav:hover{
    animation: backcolor 20s linear infinite reverse;
    animation-play-state: running; /* resume the animation */
}
@keyframes backcolor {
    from {background-position: 0 40%;}
    to {background-position: 0 400%;}
}
```

By setting animation-fill-mode: forwards, the element stays at the final position of the animation when it finishes, instead of reverting to the initial state.

By setting animation-play-state: paused initially, the animation is paused until the hover event triggers.

Finally, by setting animation-play-state: running on hover, you resume the paused animation, and it starts playing from the current position in reverse direction.